# reuse code using vcxproj not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-reuse, biicode

I tried to reuse my own code, which I have already published, and now that I'm on a new project, I write on it:

```
#include "oscarcbertram/text_color/ConsoleConfig.h"
#include "oscarcbertram/text_color/TextColor.h"
```

then I make

```
bii find
```

in the console (I'm sure I'm in the good directory), then it resolves the dependencies (actually, they all are in the deps folder) but Visual Studio doesn't reach to find them, giving me an error at the #include lines

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm on Visual Studio 2013

Thanks!

Comment: Well, from a Visual Studio resp. compiler view of things, you have to specify where to look for the headers. You have two kinds of includes, ones in quotes "" and the ones in angle brackets <>. The quotes variant starts search from the DIRECTORY where the file your include statement is in is located. The angle brackets take the configured search paths into account. With quotes you'd either have to specify a relative path, or use the angle brackets and add the "Deps" folder to your search paths. How is your actual folder structure, and how is your project configured?

Answer (score 4):

`bii find` searches for new dependencies in the project, but you have to regenerate your Visual Studio project running `bii cpp:configure` again.

Remember you should run `bii cpp:configure` with the Visual Studio cmake generator to generate the proper VS solution. Supposing you are working with Visual Studio 2013:

```
$ bii cpp:configure -G "Visual Studio 12 2013"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Actually I realized I was using Visual Studio 9 2008 as generator, even if I have recently installed Visual 2013 for editing code. Now I get this error:                                       error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'oscarcbertram/text_color/TextColor.h'                                                              What is happening? thanks

Comment: @oscarcbertram Take [this library](https://github.com/Manu343726/edalib) as an example. It runs perfectly with gcc, clang, and visual studio (>=2013). Try to create a new biicode project, open the `manu342726/edalib-tests` block, and run `bii find` and later `bii cpp:configure -G "Visual Studio 12 2013"`. Then open the visual studio solution generated at `yourproject/build/`. It works perfectly.

Comment: @oscarcbertram if you add a new dependency, you have to run `bii find` and `bii cpp:configure` again (A naked `cpp:configure` is enough, biicode keeps the parameters of the last call). Then VS prompts you that the solution has external changes. Accept them and you are ready.